# Nestjs with PassportModule custom AuthGuard inject ConfigService?

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

i want know how to inject ConfigService in PassportModule AuthGuard with custom params?

here is my code

auth.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService): Promise<IAuthModuleOptions> => {
        return {}
      }
    }),
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

github-auth.guard.ts

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  // ...

  @Get('github-oauth')
  @UseGuards(new GithubAuthGuard({}))
  async githubOAuth(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
    const user = req.user
    return await this.handleOauth(user, req, res)
  }
}
```

github-auth.guard.ts

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport'

@Injectable()
export class GithubAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('github') {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super()
  }
  //...
}
```

i call the `UseGuards` with `new GithubAuthGuard({})` because i want pass custom params.

Update:

`AuthGuard('github')` return a wraped class can accept options the then pass down to my custom strategy's `authenticate` function as the second argument.

here is my `github.strategy.ts`

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport'

class StrategyFoo extends Strategy {
    constructor(options, verify) {
        //...
    }

    // options from AuthGuard('github')
    authenticate(req, options) {
        const self = this
        const redirect_uri = options.callbackURL || this._options.callbackURL
        // ...
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class GithubBarStrategy extends PassportStrategy(StrategyFoo, 'github') {
//...
}

export const GithubStrategy = GithubBarStrategy
```

Comment: You're going to need a mixin so that you can pass option yourself and still let Nest do the injection of the `ConfigService`. What kind of values are you trying to pass? It's not clear from your code snippets

Comment: `AuthGuard('github')` return a wraped class can accept options the then pass down to my custom strategy's 'authenticate' function as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

after some research i figure it out

> Nest will not inject anything on a manually instantiated class

so just call `@UseGuards(GithubAuthGuard)` and then inject ConfigService in `github-auth.guard.ts` or `github.strategy.ts` like:

inject in `github-auth.guard.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class GithubAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('github') {
  // @Inject(ConfigService)
  // private configService: ConfigService

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    // 
    const options = {
      callbackURL: configService.get('OAuth.github.callbackURL'),
      //...
    }
    super(options)
  }

  getAuthenticateOptions(context) {
    // this also works
    return {
      callbackURL: this.configService.get('OAuth.github.callbackURL'),
      //...
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

or

inject in `github.strategy.ts`

```
class StrategyFoo extends Strategy {

  private _options: any
  constructor(options, verify) {
    //...
    this._options = options
    // ...
  }
  authenticate(req, options) {
    // ...
    let _options = {
    ...options,
    ...this._options
    }
    // ...
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class GithubBarStrategy extends PassportStrategy(StrategyFoo, 'github') {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      passReqToCallback: true,

      callbackURL: this.configService.get('OAuth.github.callbackURL'),
      // ...
    })
  }
  // ...
}
```